# Android SQLite Update query Issue

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I am having a problem to get an update query to work using the following code:

```
ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new         
ExternalDbOpenHelper(MainBarcode.this, DB_NAME);
database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String testString = "11";
String Datetime;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Datetime = dateformat.format(c.getTime());
try
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("TIMEOUT",Datetime );
    int int1 = Integer.valueOf(testString);
    database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, FRIEND_ID + " = ?",new String[] { String.valueOf(testString) });

} catch (Exception e) {                
}
database.close();
```

My database has the following columns

```
TABLE_NAME = "LOG"

FRIEND_ID = AUTO INCREMENT NUMBER

FRIEND_TIMEOUT = TIME IN A STRING
```

I am trying to update the column `FRIEND_TIMEOUT` with the current time and date by specifying the `Friend_ID`.

The ID number is a string and I'm trying to pass it to the update query.

The query runs but doesn't update the record.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: you're comparing dates as strings, and your strings are not in 'most-significant-first' ordering. Therefore `11-may-2000` will test out as LARGER than `11-jun-2016`, because `m` comes after `j` in the alphabet. you should never ever be storing dates/times as strings in the db, especially when you need to do date-based math/comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are setting wrong field name for update.
You have set "TIMEOUT" and your column name is "FRIEND_TIMEOUT".
Refer following code

```
 SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String testString = "1";
    String Datetime;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Datetime = dateformat.format(c.getTime());
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("FRIEND_TIMEOUT", Datetime);
        int int1 = Integer.valueOf(testString);
        long result = database.update("LOG", values, "FRIEND_ID" + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(testString)});
        Log.d("result", "" + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    database.close();
}
```

**Note : If you still getting this problem then add a line in catch block as above for print the exception, so you will get idea regarding issue**

Comment: Thank you my frien excellent Yes did have to add the try/catch many thanks